# Login with JPA and EL dosen't work

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

So i am trying to develop a webapp that has 4 kind of users.
The recognition of the type of the user is done automatically means the user enters his login and pwd and he will be redirectec automatically to his functionalities because all users inherit from a table in mysql DB.
The named queries is like this:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "Utilisateur.control", query="SELECT u FROM Utilisateur u WHERE u.login= :id and u.pwd= :pwd")
```

and i used it like this :

```
public int loginControl(String id,String pwd){
    try{
        Utilisateur u=em.createNamedQuery("Utilisateur.control",Utilisateur.class).setParameter("id",id).setParameter("pwd", pwd).getResultList().get(0);
        if(u!=null){
        Etudiant e=em.createNamedQuery("Etudiant.findByCinEtu",Etudiant.class).setParameter("cinEtu",u.getCin()).getResultList().get(0);
        if(e!=null){
            return 1;
        }
        Enseignant s=em.createNamedQuery("Enseignant.findByCinEns",Enseignant.class).setParameter("cinEns",u.getCin()).getResultList().get(0);
        Chefdepartement c=em.createNamedQuery("Chefdepartement.findByCinChef",Chefdepartement.class).setParameter("cinChef",s.getCinEns()).getResultList().get(0);
        if (c!=null){
            return 3;
        }
        if(s!=null){
            return 2;
        }
        return 4;
        }
    }catch (NoResultException e){
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and it returns true if the variable u is not null.
and in the managed bean it tests if the return is true it goes to a web page like this:

```
public String loginCont(){
    if(query.loginControl(id, pwd)==1){
        return "/WelcomeEtu.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    else if(query.loginControl(id, pwd)==2){
        return "/WelcomEns.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    else if(query.loginControl(id, pwd)==3){
        return "/WelcomeChef.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    else if (query.loginControl(id, pwd)==4){
        return "/WelcomeAdm.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("growl");
    FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Erreur","login ou mot de passe non valides !"));
    return"/home.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

with query is the instance of the class where i called the named query.
when i press the button :

```
<p:commandButton value="Me Connecter" action="#{login.loginCont()}"/>
```

nothing happens it just refreshes the home.xhtml.

Comment: So what int does loginControl return when you test? You're calling the loginControl-method up to 4 times, you should just assign the returnvalue to a variable instead. Also could you try to return null at the last line of loginCont?

Comment: i can't return null because it returns an url to a jsf page but i can assigna a variable and do the test once and since this is a web app i cant really test what does the class return i guess ?

Comment: You're returning "home" which is where you're already at, but because of the redirect you loose the message you just created. Why is it so hard to try returning null in the last line?